# How to smooth the surface of parts printed with Co-polyester (PET) filament

Tags: filament, post-processing, pet

Are there any techniques for getting a smooth finish for parts printed with co-polyester (PET) filaments? More specifically, I am looking for an alternative that does not roughen the look of the part - such as using sandpaper - but rather works like acetone baths for ABS.

In particular, I want to treat ColorFabb's XT filament made from the [Eastman Amphora™ 3D polymer](http://www.eastman.com/Markets/3D_Printing/Pages/Products.aspx) ([datasheet](http://ws.eastman.com/ProductCatalogApps/PageControllers/ProdDatasheet_PC.aspx?Product=71100831&sCategoryName=Generic)). This is also the polymer is also used in:

- ColorFabb [nGen and XT](http://colorfabb.com/co-polyesters)
- Taulman3D n-vent
- TripTech Athiri 1800
- 3DXTech 3DXNano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethyl acetate (sold as a MEK substitute) is supposed to work for vapor smoothing PET.  It doesn't seem very toxic (it's used to decaffinate cofee and tea, and as a nail polish remover), but you might want to look more into it.  There's a post on Printed Solid's blog where he vapor smoothed colorFabb XT and MadeSolid PET+ along with a few other filaments and got some good results.

http://printedsolid.com/blogs/news/37035395-vapor-smoothing-3d-printed-parts-pla-colorfabb-xt-t-glase-pet

The links in the blog don't work for me, but google was able to find slightly larger versions:

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0887/0138/files/blog_2014-03-20-18.38.04-1024x613.jpg?16147388421280943481

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0887/0138/files/blog_2014-03-21-18.16.28-1024x612.jpg?9543779874607042697

Comment: This seems like fairly reasonable solution for PET. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

I've found a [chart](http://www.plasticsintl.com/plastics_chemical_resistence_chart.html) which covers several plastics and solvents and only two of them ([Chloromethane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloromethane) and [Chloroform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroform)) are rated "D" which includes dissolving the material and both seem to be quite nasty and I doubt you will be able to purchase them without being placed on several lists.

Is it possible that something like [XTC-3D](http://www.smooth-on.com/Epoxy-Coatings-XTC/c1397_1429/index.html) from Smooth-On would work for you?

Also some more information on dissolving PET [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_dissolve_polyethyelene_terephthalate_PET), several sources also mention PET is affected by Hydrogen Peroxide but they do not mention to what degree the plastic is affected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing some great resources! I will certainly not be experimenting with pure ozone or phosphorus any time soon, but some product like XTC-3D could potentially be of help. All in all, it seems like PET is a fairly stable plastic chemically. Thanks!